# Express+jade: local variable not available in view

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I ran into a very basic problem but I can't seem to find the answer to it. I am working with `node.js`, `express` and I am just trying to pass a local variable into the view like this:

```
 app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render("index", {locals: {
    title: "Blog",
    }
  });
});
```

My index view is equally simple:

```
h1= title
```

But for some reason, I keep getting this error as if the local variable is never passed:

```
 500 ReferenceError: /home/spartan/Node_Projects/test/views/index.jade:1 > 1| h1= title 2| title is not defined
> 1| h1= title
  2| title is not defined
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong! Here are the versions I am using:

- Express: 3.0.0alpha1
- node.JS: 0.6.14
- Jade:    0.24.0

Someone please help so I can actually move on to learning node + express!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should pass the variable without the `locals`. This is probably new in express 3.0.0

```
res.render("index", {title: "Blog"});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was it! I was just following an old tutorial and had no idea what was wrong..

Answer (score 4):

h1 = title tries to evaluate it locally, the title you sent and that one is different. To understand the difference see:

```
- var title = 'my title' // - allows writing code
h1 = title
```

The one you should use is:

```
h1 #{title}
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me that, I understand that difference now. I was so sure that was it, but unfortunately, when I changed my view to just `h1 #{title}` it gave me the exact same error message... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10199840/1265207) that I made few hours ago to a smiliar question (+ deal with layout). It shows how to pass data when rendering. (Express 3.0.0 complient)

Comment: Thank you, your response had the answer I was looking for as well.